# Python substring from beginning and return index (have duplicate case)

Tags: python, list, algorithm, indexing, substring

I have a long string and a list of substring of the corresponding long string.

Example 1:

String:

```
" This is paragraph one "
```

List of substrings: `["This", "is paragraph", "one"]`

I need to return the index for the corresponding substring

Result: `[[0,4], [5, 17], [18, 21]]`

Example 2:
(Could have more white space and could have duplicate substring)

String:

```
"
This is a book       a book.
"
```

List:
List of substrings: `["This", "is a", "book", "a", "book"]`

Result: `[[0,4], [5, 9], [10, 14], [21,22], [23, 27]]`

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
s = "This is a book       a book."
subs = ["This", "is a", "book", "a", "book"]

bounds = []
end = 0
for sub in subs:
    bounds.append((start := s[end:].find(sub) + end, end := start + len(sub)))
print(bounds)
```

It gives:

```
[(0, 4), (5, 9), (10, 14), (21, 22), (23, 27)]
```

For amusement, the same using `re`:

```
s = "This is a book       a book."
subs = ["This", "is a", "book", "a", "book"]

import re 
re.match(".*".join(f"({t})" for t in subs), s).regs[1:]
```

It gives:

```
((0, 4), (5, 9), (10, 14), (21, 22), (23, 27))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, this cannot handle in "example2"

Comment: Also, please do not answer invalid questions.  "No effort" postings fall into this class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator function:

```
def get_matches(s, sub):
   inds = []
   for i in sub:
      if (k:=[j for j in range(len(s)) if s[j:].startswith(i) and (not inds or j > max(inds))]):
         yield [k[0], k[0]+len(i)]
         inds.append(k[0])
         
s = 'This is a book       a book.'
subs = ['This', 'is a', 'book', 'a', 'book']
print(list(get_matches(s, subs)))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 4], [5, 9], [10, 14], [21, 22], [23, 27]]
```

Comment: This works! Thank you!